# Is this proof correct that $\Bbb{H}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ is a conformal map?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Let $\Bbb{H}:=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2: y>0\}$ be the hyperbolic halfplane induced with the hyperbolic riemannian metric $$(g_\Bbb{H})_{(x,y)}=\frac{1}{y^2}\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $$ I consider the euclidean plane $\Bbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean metric $g=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $. I want to show that the identity map $$\operatorname{id}:(\Bbb{H}, g_\Bbb{H})\rightarrow (\Bbb{R},g)$$ is conformal.

By definition I need to find $\lambda: \Bbb{H}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $$g_{(x,y)}(D\operatorname{id}|_{(x,y)} X,D\operatorname{id}|_{(x,y)} Y)=\lambda^2(x,y)(g_\Bbb{H})_{(x,y)}(X,Y)$$ for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb{H}$ and for all $X,Y\in T_{(x,y)}\Bbb{H}$.

**Proof** Let $(x,y)\in \Bbb{H}$, i.e. $y>0$. Then $$\begin{align}(g_\Bbb{H})_{(x,y)}(X,Y)=\frac{1}{y^2}(X,Y)\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix} X \\ Y \end{matrix} \right)\end{align}$$ On the other hand $$\begin{align}g_{(x,y)}(D\operatorname{id}|_{(x,y)} X,D\operatorname{id}|_{(x,y)} Y)&=g_{(x,y)}(X,Y)\\&=(X,Y)\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix} X \\ Y \end{matrix} \right)\end{align}$$ So we see that we can define $\lambda: \Bbb{H}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}_{>0};~~(x,y)\mapsto \frac{1}{y}$ then $\lambda^2(x,y)=\frac{1}{y^2}$ and we get the equality we wanted.

Is this mathematically correct?

Comment: Your proof is fine. The problem statement is a little troublesome: the map denoted $\operatorname{id}$ is called the *inclusion map*, not the *identity map*. The terminology *identity map* presupposes that the domain and range are, well, identical.

Comment: @LeeMosher ah okey I see, thanks a lot for the comment!

Comment: @LeeMosher sorry short question, is it really true that $g(X,Y)=(X,Y) G (X,Y)^T$ where $G$ is the matrix corresponding to the riemannian metric?

Comment: @LeeMosher because I think I did a mistake and it should be $g(X,Y)=X^T G Y$

Comment: That's a good point: presumably, from the notation $X,Y\in T_{(x,y)}\Bbb{H}$, $X$ and $Y$ are being identified with column matrices representing elements of $T_{(x,y)}\Bbb{H}$? in which case $X^T G Y$ looks correct.

Comment: @LeeMosher perfect thanks! (yes $X,Y$ are column matrices)